# Mongodb Query Multiple data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I have persons table

and I want to query 2 names at the same time to show their data.

I'm doing it like this

```js
{"name":{"Jollibee", "Mcdo"}
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$in` operator:

```js
collection.find({ "name": { "$in": ["Jollibee", "Mcdo"] }})
```

Comment: Thank you. this works. May I ask why $and is not working?

Comment: Because your query means that you try to find document were the `name` property is equal to the object `{"Jollibee", "Mcdo"}`, and that is not valid. If you want to find multiple values for a property, you can either use `$or` operator for each value explicitly, or  `$in` operator that takes an array of all the values that you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but you can use the OR condition, like

```
{"$or":  [ { name: "Jollibee" }, { name: "Mcdo" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use implicit `$and`

```
collection.find( { $and: [ { name: { $eq: "Jollibee" } }, { name: { $eq: "Mcdo"} } ] } )
```